# Cannot find symbol class DocumentListenOptions

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, react-native

I am trying to recover 6 months old app but I can't build it.

This is a react-native app for Android/iOS. I am using "**Android Studio**" to build this app.

I can't build the app because it fails to compile:

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Compiler errors:

> error: cannot find symbol class DocumentListenOptions
>     error: cannot find symbol class QueryListenOptions
>     error: cannot find symbol method getDownloadUrl()

Code from error:

```
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentListenOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldPath;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ListenerRegistration;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryListenOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

public void onSnapshot(final String listenerId, final ReadableMap queryListenOptions) {
if (!collectionSnapshotListeners.containsKey(listenerId)) {
  final EventListener<QuerySnapshot> listener = new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot querySnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException exception) {
      if (exception == null) {
        handleQuerySnapshotEvent(listenerId, querySnapshot);
      } else {
        ListenerRegistration listenerRegistration = collectionSnapshotListeners.remove(listenerId);
        if (listenerRegistration != null) {
          listenerRegistration.remove();
        }
        handleQuerySnapshotError(listenerId, exception);
      }
    }
  };
  QueryListenOptions options = new QueryListenOptions();
  if (queryListenOptions != null) {
    if (queryListenOptions.hasKey("includeDocumentMetadataChanges")
      && queryListenOptions.getBoolean("includeDocumentMetadataChanges")) {
      options.includeDocumentMetadataChanges();
    }
    if (queryListenOptions.hasKey("includeQueryMetadataChanges")
      && queryListenOptions.getBoolean("includeQueryMetadataChanges")) {
      options.includeQueryMetadataChanges();
    }
  }

  ListenerRegistration listenerRegistration = this.query.addSnapshotListener(options, listener);
  collectionSnapshotListeners.put(listenerId, listenerRegistration);
 }
}
```

"not a full code, just the place I get an error from"

So it:

- **cannot resolve symbol "QueryListenOptions"**
- **cannot resolve method "includeDocumentMetadataChanges"**
- **cannot resolve method "addSnapshotListener(options, listener)"**

---

And for this error:

> cannot find symbol method getDownloadUrl()

```
private WritableMap getUploadTaskAsMap(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    WritableMap resp = Arguments.createMap();

    if (taskSnapshot != null) {
      resp.putDouble("bytesTransferred", taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred());
      resp.putString("downloadURL", taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() != null ? taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString() : null);

      StorageMetadata d = taskSnapshot.getMetadata();
      if (d != null) {
        WritableMap metadata = getMetadataAsMap(d);
        resp.putMap("metadata", metadata);
      }

      resp.putString("ref", taskSnapshot.getStorage().getPath());
      resp.putString("state", this.getTaskStatus(taskSnapshot.getTask()));
      resp.putDouble("totalBytes", taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
    }
    return resp;
  }
```

**cannot resolve method "getDownloadUrl"**

So if you have any suggestions for these two problems please share your knowledge.

Thank you! :)

Comment: still not solved, waiting for suggestions :)

Comment: Release notes?  Looks like calls to some of those changed back in May? [See this](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) Look for the SDK update, May 2nd, in section: Cloud Firestore version 16.0.0